# Filtering by alphabet

Tags: collection-filtering

Is it possible to bring all goods where the value of the "name" attribute begins particular letter, for example "". (without assigning additional attributes). Maybe there is a ready solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smae_ivan,You can do this

by operator like  on where condition

```
   addFieldToFilter(array(
        array(
            'attribute' => 'name',// name is field name 
            'like'        => $youtletter.'%',
            );
```

More:http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento